# Find all the roots of the equation $z^2 + |z| = 0$ .

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Find all the roots of the equation $z^2 + |z| = 0$ .

My solution goes like this:

> Let $z=a+ib$, and $z^4=|z|^2\implies a^4+4a^3ib+6a^2(ib)^2+4a(ib)^3+(ib)^4=a^4+4a^3ib-6a^2b^2-4ab^3i=a^2+b^2\implies a^4+b^4+4a^3ib-6a^2b^2-4aib^3+b^4=a^2+b^2\implies a^4+b^4+4i(a^3-b^3)=a^2+b^2+6a^2b^2\implies a^4+b^4-2a^2b^2+4i(a^3-b^3)=a^2+b^2+4a^2b^2\implies (a^2-b^2)^2+4i(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)=a^2+b^2+4a^2b^2$. Now, since, $\text{R.H.S} \in\Bbb R$ and hence $Im(\text{L.H.S})=0$. Thus, $4(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)=0$ so, $a=b$ and $a^2+b^2+ab$. So all $z=a+ib$ are solutions of the equations iff $a=b$ or $\text{if}\space(x=a,y=b)$ satisfies $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy=0$.

Is the above solution correct?

Comment: What does “$(a,b)$ satisfies $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy$” mean?

Comment: What does “or $(a,b)$ satisfies $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$” mean?

Comment: Your solution suggests that $5+5i$ is a solution. It is not.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Sorry for the blurry context. I have edited it...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Then $a=b=5$ and hence $5^2+5^2+25\neq 0$ so $(x=5,y=5)$ is not a solution ...

Comment: I think it's reasonably clear that we must have $|z|=1$ to solve the equation. I suppose that simplifies things.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Can you please elucidate upon the context?

Comment: Where does $(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$ come from?

Comment: @Franklin „iff $a=b$ or …“ - and $a=b$ certainly holds when both are $5$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Equating the imaginary part of L.H.S to be zero...

Comment: But $(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)=a^3-b^3\ne a^3b-ab^3$. Besides, what about the real part?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok , editing again to show more steps  

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Edited

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yeah , I think that's the loop hole of my solution as I didn't solved the equation of  real part simulataneously with the complex part...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $z^2+|z|=0$, then $z^2=-|z|\leqslant0$. The only complex numbers whose square is a real number smaller than or equal to $0$ are those numbers $z$ of the form $\lambda i$, for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. But then$$z^2+|z|=0\iff-\lambda^2+|\lambda|=0,$$whose only solutions are $-1$, $0$, and $1$. Therefore, the solutions of your equation are $-i$, $0$, and $i$.

Comment: You are a genius! I get it now....How do you come up with these elegant strategies? Maybe, heuristics...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $z^2+|z|=0$ it follows that
$$-z^2=|z|
$$
Taking the modulus of both sides we get
$$|-z^2| = |(|z|)| \implies |z|^2=|z| \implies |z|=0 \,\,\text{or}\,\, 1
$$

Case 1: If $|z|=0$ then $z=0$. And $0$ is indeed a solution.

Case 2: If $|z|=1$ then $z^2=-1$ so $z=-i$ or $+i$. And $-i$, $+i$ are indeed both solutions.