# Are these two simple equations the same

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve for the complex number z in this equation:
$$\vert z\vert = -z^2$$
And according to the solution, the next step is taking the abs of both sides:
$$ \vert\vert z \vert\vert = \left\vert -z^2 \right\vert $$
Which is where the problem lies. I noticed that if you plugged $i$ in as $z$, everything's fine, but if you plugged in $1$ for $z$ only the second equation holds. I'm pretty sure that for them to be the same equations, their solutions have to be the same - but I *am* using the same operation on both sides so the equation should hold and... it doesn't (some property of complex numbers idk) and I'm confused, pls help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623704/find-all-the-roots-of-the-equation-z2-z-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is like squaring an equation in the real numbers.  The first equation implies the second, but the second does not imply the first.  You have thrown away information by the operation you applied.  In the reals, squaring throws away the information of whether an expression was greater or less than $0$.  In the complex field, taking the modulus throws away the information of the angle of the number.

In your problem, the left side of the first equation is always real and nonnegative.  If we are paying attention, that tells us that $z$ is purely imaginary because its square is real and nonpositive.

Comment: Ohh, I see, so my assumption *was* wrong